# MV exclude folder not working

Tags: bash, mv, shopt

I'm trying to copy all of the files/directories inside a folder but would like to exclude one folder as I want all the other file to be inside that folder. To better demonstrate below is the folder structure

```
- VideosFolder
      L File1
      L File2
      L File3
      L TutorialFolder
```

Now I want `File1` `File2` `File3` to be moved to `TutorialFolder` like so

```
- VideosFolder
      L TutorialFolder
          L File1
          L File2
          L File3
```

I tried this command

> `mv ~/Desktop/VideosFolder/!(TutorialFolder) TutorialFolder`

But I get this error

> mv: cannot stat '/home/user/Desktop/VideosFolder/!(TutorialFolder)': No such file or directory

I checked if the `shopt extglob` is enabled and it is indeed enabled. So I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Is that the _actual_ command that you are using? What directory is your current directory when executing that command? Are you sure that you are using `bash` and that the `extglob` shell option is set? I can only reproduce the error if I quote the destination path (meaning the glob won't expand). Assuming you are located in `~/Desktop/VideosFolder`, and that you have set the `extglob` shell option with  `shopt -s extglob` in `bash`, than your command will work.

Answer (score 1):

You could just run

```
mv * TutorialFolder/
```

While in `VideosFolder/`. This will move all files and directories (not starting with a `.`) into `TutorialFolder/`. As you can't move a directory into itself, you will likely get a warning message along the lines of

```
mv: cannot move 'TutorialFolder' to a subdirectory of itself, 'TutorialFolder/TutorialFolder'
```

This is expected and just means that `mv` hasn't moved `TutorialFolder`.

Comment: This does work but it's gives a warning. I was thinking of a more cleaner way like what if I want to exclude 2 folder or more then this solution will not fix it. I was really hoping to get an answer about extglob approach as this is more flexible

Answer (score 0):

The other answer works but this is a cleaner way with no errors assuming that you are inside `VideosFolder`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! \( -name TutorialFolder -o -name '.' \) -exec mv {} TutorialFolder/ \;
```

That will find every file and directory in the current directory where the name is not equal to `TutorialFolder` and `.` (which is the current directory itself) and then use `-exec` to `mv` them into `TutorialFolder`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Rsync command.Rsync is a fast and versatile command line utility that synchronizes files and folders between two locations over a remote shell.

```
 rsync -a --exclude 'TutorialFolder' ~/Desktop/VideosFolder/  ~/Desktop/VideosFolder/TutorialFolder/
```